# Dataset for textual adverts matching

Tags: python, dataset, jupyter, ads

I'm new to machine learning and I'm trying to create a machine learning classifier using python & Jupyter to match textual advertisements to websites that they will be displayed on. Is there any dataset that I could make use of?

Comment: Please read the description for the [tag:ml] tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could get a lot of datas to train your NN e.g. on the U.S. [government site](https://www.data.gov)
Or you load `datasets` from `sklearn`: e.g.: 
`from sklearn import datasets` ([link to sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/index.html#dataset-examples))